# AppCenter iOS distribution not visble on install page

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, appcenter

I have setup build and release pipelines in Azure Devops for an iOS Xamarin.Forms app. The release pipeline pushes the ipa file to AppCenter and distributes it. This all seems to work fine. See screenshot

[image: Appcenter]

However, when I go to the install page on my iOS device, I don't see the version there, just the latest version that was released 2 years ago:

[image: Why]

The ipa is signed with a distribution certificate and an adhoc provisioning profile which includes the UUID. The device is also connected to the appcenter account.

I am assuming that the error message is related to the older version.

Why is the app not showing on the install page?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is really stupid. Turns out that everything went ok, but since we changed something about the versioning, the newer versions didn't show up at the top. We had to order by 'Recent' instead of the default 'Version' to get it displayed :)